# Prove: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets then $A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets then $A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$?

Let $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$

Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B\cap C$

Suppose $x \in A$. 
Then $x \in A\cup B$ and $x \in  A\cup C$. 
So $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$

Suppose $x \in B\cap C$. 
Then $x \in  B$ and $x \in C$ 
Since $x \in B$, then $x \in A\cup B$. 
Since $x \in C$, then $x \in A\cup C$. 
So $x \in A\cup B$ and $x \in A\cup C$. 
So $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

So if $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$, then $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

Suppose $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

Then $x \in A\cup B$ and $x \in A\cup C$.

Suppose $x \in A$. 
Then $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$.

Suppose $x \notin A$. 
Since $A\cup B$, we must have $x \in B$. 
Since $A\cup C$, we must have $x \in C$. 
So $x \in B\cap C$. 
Then $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$.

Since $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$. 
Then $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$.

So if $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$, then $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$.

We conclude that $A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

Is this acceptable???

Comment: Yes! This proof is correct

Comment: Some small comments. You say "Since $A \cup B$, we must have $x \in B$," and similarly with $A\cup C$; rather you should say "Since $x \in A \cup B$, ..." You also have the incomplete sentence "Since $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$." You should finish that sentence with something like "we have covered all possibilities." Other than that, your proof is correct.